# Launchpad Icon in my Launchpad

Tags: launchpad

I have accidently "dragged" launchpad onto the launchpad icon in my dock, thus it added the launchpad icon into my launchpad, how can I remove it from my launchpad?

Help appreciated![image]

Comment: Right click + remove ?

Comment: you can't right click on launchpad ...

Comment: sorry, Open Launchpad and Hold Option key.....ect

Comment: You can't delete Apple apps from Launchpad by holding the option key and pressing the "x"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com)

Launchpad Manager will allow you to delete *any* app from your Launchpad. Just open it, select Launchpad (or any other app) and <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ backspace</kbd>.

[image: Launchpad Manager Image]

Answer (score 2):

To delete Apple aps from Launchpad without installing another questionable program from www you can do it your self from Terminal.

> sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db "DELETE from apps
>   WHERE title='APPNAME';" && killall Dock

...replacing “APPNAME” with the name of the application you want to remove from Launchpad :)

Comment: How about adding one?